# Binding one grid view row which is nested in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I was hoping to ask for some help.

This is the context, 
I have one grid view row which populate site locations. Using this grid view row (Gridview1), I then use the item location of each row to create a nested gridview(Gridview2), which shows order numbers per location. I then use the orders in the second gridview, to populate a third nested grid(Gridview3), which shows ingredients which are required for that order.

Now in the third grid view, I have a reason which is Inputted by the user as to why the ingredient could not be picked.

My problem is the following: 
Once a user Inputs a reason, is it possible to only bind the Row of the grid view where the reason was Inputted instead of having to save a databind on the entire Gridview1 which ends up binding Gridview2 and Gridview3. I’d like to save processing time and time the user has to wait for the entire report to databind, which is why I would just want the one row to update

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What type of application is this? is it Xamarin Forms, Razor, or what?

Comment: Hi, it is asp.net